# JPA Not Eagerly Loading Everything

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I am having a problem leveraging JPA 1.0 via OpenJPA implementation. My data model consists of a Trip which has a OneToMany relationship with Leg and a OneToMany relationship with Passenger. Leg and Passenger have an assocation in PassengerLeg. This is mapped as bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne. So essentially I have a diamond in my data model. If a trip has 2 legs and 3 passengers, there will be 6 passengerLegs. For various use cases I have needs to go each direction from each entity. Right now, when I attempt to eagerly load everything, the leg field in PassengerLeg will be null and I cannot figure out why. Here is a skimpy representation of my classes:

```
@Entity
public class Trip {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "trip", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Leg> legs;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "trip", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Passenger> passengers;

}

@Entity
public class Leg {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "TRIP_ID")
  private Trip trip;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "leg", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<PassengerLeg> passengers;

}

@Entity
public class Passenger {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "TRIP_ID")
  private Trip trip;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "passenger", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<PassengerLeg> legs;

}

@Entity
public class PassengerLeg {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "LEG_ID")
  private Leg leg; //this will be null

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "PASSENGER_ID")
  private Passenger passenger;

}
```

I've spent countless hours reading documentation and anything I can find on Google to figure out what might cause this, but I have not had any luck. Anyone have any ideas what would cause this? Let me know if you need any more information about classes/annotations.

Comment: Ain't you missing `mappedBy` in those OneToMany annotations?

Comment: Thank you. I added in the mappedBy properties I forgot in this example, but are in my application. There was also a missing fetch property on a OneToMany annotation as well.

Answer (score 7):

JPA Never loads many side eagerly since it can be time consuming operation. Default fetch As mentioned in JPA Specs

1. One To One --->Fetch Eager
2. One To Many ---> Fetch Lazy
3. Many to one---> fetch Eager
4. Many To Many---> Fetch Lazy

also I will not advice you to go for Eager fetch since it is heavy operation

Comment: So when I encounter such a situation where I need to traverse the many-to-many, do you have recommendations on how to handle it? I cannot imagine an eager fetch is slower than fetching my base object and manually traversing it to retrieve all the objects as I have a need for them. Not to mention, even when I am explicitly setting it to eager fetch, it is still not eagerly fetching the data.

Comment: Use Joins explicitly in EBJ QL query so that data required can be fetched.[JPQL](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying)

Comment: Any other thoughts since the site you linked says for JPA 1.0 cannot do nested fetches which would be needed in this situation??

Comment: Use Left Join or inner join depending upon the situation.