# JPA @OneToMany not fetching the childern

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, eager-loading, many-to-one

Following is the table structure:

```
desc customer_survey
Name        Null     Type         
----------- -------- ------------ 
SURVEYID    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
CUSTNO      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
SRNO                 NUMBER(10)   
AVGRATINGS           NUMBER(5,2)  
COMMENTS             VARCHAR2(50) 
SENTON               DATE         
RESPONDEDON          DATE         

desc Survey_response
Name             Null     Type         
---------------- -------- ------------ 
SURVEYRESPONSEID NOT NULL NUMBER(10)   
RATINGS          NOT NULL NUMBER(2)    
QNO              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
SURVEYID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
```

Java classes:

```
 public class CustomerSurvey implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="customerSurvey", 
     cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<SurveyResponse> responses;
 ......

 public class SurveyResponse {

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="SURVEYID", referencedColumnName="surveyId")
private CustomerSurvey customerSurvey;

 ......
```

Client code:

```
 List<CustomerSurvey> surveys = workService.getSurveysByCustomer("testCNo2");
 System.out.println("surveys size = " + surveys.size());

 for(CustomerSurvey survey: surveys) {
System.out.println("getting responses from the survey object now..");
Set<SurveyResponse> responses = survey.getResponses();
System.out.println("responses size= .." + responses.size());
 }
```

console shows:

surveys size = 1
   getting responses from the survey object now..
   responses size= ..0

whereas there are 7 responses in the DB for the selected survey.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711148/jpa-not-eagerly-loading-everything) helped. 
I set the collection back to lazy. And
Inside persistence class, within transaction after getting the resultset, I am now calling getResponses as:

```
List<CustomerSurvey> surveys = query.getResultList();
for (CustomerSurvey survey : surveys) {
    Set<SurveyResponse> responses = survey.getResponses();
}
```

that populates the responses.

Answer (score 4):

Enable logging and look if the SQL is correct.

It is hard to tell from your incomplete code, but in general a OneToMany should not use a JoinColumn it should use a mappedBy, and the join column in the ManyToOne should reference the Id of the object.

Also ensure you are setting both sides of the relationship when you insert your objects.

Comment: I changed my code as per your comment. query in log file shows: SELECT 'com.ge.dsp.iwork.entity.CustomerSurvey' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,SURVEY.AVGRATINGS,SURVEY.COMMENTS,B0.CITY,B0.COMPANYNAME,B0.CUSTNO,B0.EMAIL,B0.FIRSTNAME,B0.GENDER,B0.LASTNAME,B0.MIDINIT,B0.PHONE,B0."STATE",B0.STREETADDRESS,B0.TITLE,B0.ZIPCODE,SURVEY.RESPONDEDON,SURVEY.SENTON,C0.CUSTNO,C0.DATECREATED,C0.DATEUPDATED,C0.DESCRIPTION,C0.SRNO,C0.STATUS,SURVEY.SURVEYID FROM CUSTOMER_SURVEY SURVEY INNER JOIN CUSTOMER B0 ON SURVEY.CUSTNO = B0.CUSTNO LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVICE_REQUEST C0 ON SURVEY.SRNO = C0.SRNO WHERE B0.CUSTNO = <'testCNo2'>

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to populate the relationship with a jpql fetch query:

"select survey from Surveys survey join fetch survey.responses"

I had the same problem and still can't find out what is going wrong. In my case the parent entity was loaded by a jpql query, and so extending this provided a workaround

Comment: It helps me. Probably the page https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying can help somebody in future

Comment: I faced w/ another issue regarding this solution, mentioned in my previous comment:    Duplicate Data and Huge Joins
One issue with join fetching is that duplicate data can be returned. For example consider join fetching an Employee's phoneNumbers relationship. If each Employee has 3 Phone objects in its phoneNumbers collection, the join will require to bring back n*3 rows. As there are 3 phone rows for each employee row, the employee row will be duplicated 3 times. 
One alternative solution to join fetch that does not suffer from duplicate data is using Batch Fetching.